# Adjusting the increments for brightness changes in Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, shortcut-keys, brightness

When I adjust with the mouse (Preferences >> LXQT Settings >> Brightness) I can get fine gradations but when I adjust with my assigned Shortcut Keys (Preferences >> LXQT Settings >> Shortcut Keys) the gradations are too large. I have sensitive eyes and need the brightness just right.

Is there a file somewhere where I can punch in new values for the Shortcut Keys (brightness-i and brightness-d) so as to change the amount of brightness change per keystroke?

Comment: I'm not aware of any (*which doesn't mean there isn't one*), but I think the -i & -d options represent the `-i` & `-d` options for `lxqt-config-brightness` which offers a `-s` or set a specific value between 1 & 100.  Maybe setting a specific value may work for you (*or program specific values to specific keyboard shortcuts*).  You can use `lxqt-config-brightness --help` to view the reference manual page for the tool  (do note that tool may not work on external displays, desktops, but will also effect external display on some models... ie. hardware specific results can  be expected)

Comment: Some days my eyes are more sensitive than others. When it's bad I first get the correct brightness - in the ballpark - with the keyboard shortcuts and then fine-tune with the mouse. Then all subsequent keyboard changes are okay for that session. I find I often change the brightness for different web pages, along with the volume. Keyboard shortcuts for volume changes are more subtle.